# CURL запрос в C#

Tags: c#, post, curl

Не могу сделать запрос вот такого вида: 
curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} -d grant_type=client_credentials https://us.battle.net/oauth/token

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать данный запрос на C#? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы лучше дайте какой запрос должен быть, что отправлять и так далее, а не "переведите `CURL`, часть людей вовсе не знают о его существование, но умею делать запросы. Вы такой формулировкой делаете вопрос узкоспециализированным.

Comment: POST запрос. Мне нужно получить access token для работы с API. Для его получения нужно отправить id клиента и его секрет, что-то типа пары "ключ:значение", как я понял. В ответ я должен получить данные в формате json, в которых и будет access token.

Comment: Документация есть?

Comment: https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/using-oauth/client-credentials-flow

Comment: Наверно будет нечто на подобие [такого](https://pastebin.com/UZY1kZKX). `-u` - это заголовок авторизации, как я понял отправляется он в Base64, в кодировке ASCII (тут поиграйтесь, может что не так написал). `-d` - это данные в формате "формы". Если все сработало, то напишите в ответ ваш конечный результат.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, всё работает!)

Answer (score 1):

Эх, попросил ведь я вас написать то, что у вас в итоге получилось. Ну ок, делаю я.

Код будет примерно следующим:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{client_id}:{client_secret}")));

    var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
    });

    var resp = await client.PostAsync("https://us.battle.net/oauth/token", data);
    resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Где:

- `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` - авторизация, в CURL это `-u`. Тут на сколько я понял должна отправляться строка в кодировке ASCII, которая закодирована в Base64. Не проверял, поиграйтесь с ней и найдите то, что вам надо.
- `data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]` - это аналог `-d`, который должен составить `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` контент для отправки.
- `await client.PostAsync("https://us.battle.net/oauth/token", data);` - отправляем данные POST запросом на указанный адрес.
- `resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` - выводим Exception, если сервер дал нам что либо, кроме успешного заголовка.
- `await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` - берем из ответа данные в виде текста.

---

Повторюсь, я не проверял данный код. Если будут проблемы, то стоит поиграться с заголовком авторизации, остальное должно подходить под CURL.